# ArrayList populating outside the method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist

Please check the updated code. It is saying arraylist is null, while trying to get the element from the oncreate method. By the way I'm adding the elements to the arraylist in inner class. 
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks..

```
private ArrayList<String> imageName;
ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> test;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = this;
    listView = findViewById(R.id.clipslistview);
    test = new ArrayList<>();
    credentialProvider();
    setTransferUtility();
    getAll();
    Toast.makeText(context, test.get(0)+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

Thread thread = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        final ListObjectsV2Request req = new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName("bucket-1234314-**********").withStartAfter(".jpg").withMaxKeys(10);
        ListObjectsV2Result result;

        imageNames = new ArrayList<>();

        result =  amazonS3Client.listObjectsV2(req);


        for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary :
                result.getObjectSummaries()) {
            clipNames.add(objectSummary.getKey()+"");
            Log.d("TEEEST", objectSummary.getKey());
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: is that thread called ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html see this link

Comment: Why you need a separate thread to add data into list? where you have started that thread?

Comment: Because there is a network operation thread in between. So where I'm getting my elements to arrraylist.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>():

Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       names.add("Hi");
       names.add("KK");
       names.add("Hello");
    }
};

thread.start();

public void lengthOflit() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext, names.size()+"", Length.SHORT).show;
}
```

**FYI**

No need to use Thread for adding data in  to your `ArrayList`

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>():
names.add("Hi");
names.add("KK");
names.add("Hello");
```

Comment: I used thread because there is a network operation in between from where I'm getting my elements. For that network operation I need to run it on a different thread.

Comment: No, May because Im adding elements inside innerclass.

Comment: Do you know how to access the elements that were added to arraylist in innerclass like Thread thread = new Thread() { public void run() { names.add(something); } }

Comment: like this **`names.get(0)`**  **`names.get(1)`**  **`names.get(2)`**